# IDE - auto-update imports when moving files between libs/barrels

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, ide, nrwl

We are using nrwl/nx to split our typescript project up in smaller libs, but refactoring is a real pain.

e.g. when we move a single file from one app/lib to a new lib, the import statements in the whole project must be updated and must respect the tsconfig path mappings and barrel files.

Here is a GitHub test-project with code and detailed description: [nx-refactor](https://github.com/tmtron/nx-refactor)
There is also a branch [expected_refactoring](https://github.com/tmtron/nx-refactor/tree/expected_refactoring) with the expected refactoring result.

We use IntelliJ Idea and VsCode. However none of them seem to handle this case correctly. We also failed to find a suitable extension for this case in either IDE.

I guess that this kind of refactoring is something quite common, thus I am surprised, that his is not supported.
Can anyone recommend an extension, another IDE/editor or tool that can handle this case?

References:

- IntellIJ does not handle barrels when moving a file: [#WEB-44288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44288)
- same for VsCode

  - extension [move-ts](https://github.com/stringham/move-ts) also does not help

Comment: have you managed to solve this issue? currently having the same problem

Comment: unfortunately not - I hope it will be fixed in intellij soon: [#WEB-44288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44288)

Comment: this utility can also be useful in some cases: https://github.com/luchsamapparat/refactor-imports

Comment: added a feature request to nrwl/nx: [#12058: move generator should support directories and single files](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12058)

Answer (score 1):

Since [#WEB-44288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44288) is still not fixed, I came up with a workaround.
If you experience this issue, please watch the [IntelliJ issue #WEB-44288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44288)

The idea is to create an empty file in the new barrel and then use [Move Module members](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-module-members-dialog.html)

Details (for example in [nx-refactor](https://github.com/tmtron/nx-refactor)):

- in the target barrel `index.ts` file add `export * from './lib/file-to-move';`

  - NOTE: this statement will currently show an error  ignore the error
- now open the source file that we want to move: `libs/lib-a/src/lib/file-to-move.ts`

  - set the cursor to a top-level symbol (the `TO_MOVE` constant) and press F6 to open the [Move Module members](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-module-members-dialog.html) dialogue
  - set the `To:` path to the target file (that we have just referenced in the `index.ts` file): `[..]/lib-b\src\lib\file-to-move.ts`
  - hint: to select all members click CTRL-A and hit space to select all checkboxes
  - press `Refactor`
- now all imports are correctly updated
- final clean-up:

  - delete the original source file: `libs/lib-a/src/lib/file-to-move.ts`
  - and remove the export in the source barrel file: `libs/lib-a/src/index.ts`

Comment: Struggling with the same, I can confirm it works. The creation and export of an empty file before move is not necessary though.

Comment: @Bielik thanks. you are right, I've updated my answer.